Construct a maximal Salem-Spencer set $A\subset\mathbb{N}$ such that $\exists\ x\in\mathbb{N}\setminus A$ that makes only one three-term A.P.
A Salem-Spencer set $A\subset\mathbb{N}$ is one that has no three-term A.P's.
A maximal Salem-Spencer set $A\subset\mathbb{N}$ has the added property that $A\cup \{x\}$ is not Salem-Spencer if $x\in\mathbb{N}\setminus A.$

Give an example of/construct a maximal Salem-Spencer set
$A\subset\mathbb{N}$ such that $\exists\ x\in\mathbb{N}\setminus A$
that makes exactly (only) one three-term A.P. with two other members of $A.$

So $x$ is not a part of two separate three-term A.P's.
Maybe you can already do this with Skerez's sequence, using the definition, "$a(n)-1$ in ternary $= n-1$ in binary;" but I am not sure about it.

Maybe we can greedily construct such a sequence as follows:
We plan on making $x=1$, so start with $2,3\in A.$ And thereafter put the next number in $A$ if and only if:

It avoids three-term A.P's with other members already in $A.$
It doesn't form a three-term A.P. with $1,$ because we want $x=1$ to be involved in only one three-term A.P..

So the first few terms are $2,3,6,7,14,15,17,18,\ldots.$ As pointed out in the comments, this is https://oeis.org/A092482 without $1.$
But I see no reason for this set to be maximal (although it may well be maximal - I just don't know).

See OEIS sequence A092482.

@RobertIsrael thanks. That doesn't answer the question though, as I don't see why that sequence should be maximal.

You're almost there. Here is a proof that one can indeed find a set $A$ satisfying your conditions.
For $k\geq 3$, let $I_k=\lbrace k,2k-1 \rbrace$ (thus $\lbrace 1 \rbrace \cup I_k$ is a three-term AP).
Definition 1. A set $A\subseteq {\mathbb N}$ is nice iff it is  Salem-Spencer and $I_k\not\subseteq A$ for every $k\geq 3$.
Thus, the set $A$ we're looking for must be nice.
Definition 2. A nice set $A\subseteq {\mathbb N}$ has proprerty $P_k$ iff for every $j\in[|3...k|]$, wa can find $x_j\in I_j$, $y_j,z_j\in A$ such that $\lbrace x_j,y_j,z_j\rbrace$ is a three-term AP.
For example, the set $A=\lbrace 2,3,8\rbrace$ has property $P_3$ (with $x_3=5,y_3=2,z_3=8$).
Then we have :
Fundamental lemma. Suppose that a finite $A\subseteq {\mathbb N}$ satisfies $P_k$. Then, we can find $b,c\in {\mathbb N} \setminus A$ such that $A'=A\cup\lbrace b,c\rbrace$ satisfies $P_{k+1}$.
Proof of fundamental lemma. Since $A$ is nice, there is an $x_{k+1}\in I_{k+1}\setminus A$. Let $m=\max(A)$, and let $C$ be a constant to be defined later (it will turn out that any $C\gt 2m-1$ works).
Let $b\geq C$, and let $c=2b-x_{k+1}$, $A'=A\cup\lbrace b,c\rbrace$.
Can there be in $A'$ a three-term AP of the form $\lbrace a_1 \lt a_2 \lt a_3\rbrace$  with $a_1,a_2,a_3\in A$ ? Certainly not, since $A$ is Salem-Spencer.
Can there be in $A'$ a three-term AP of the form $\lbrace a_1 \lt a_2 \lt b\rbrace$ or  $\lbrace a_1 \lt a_2 \lt c\rbrace$ with $a_1,a_2\in A$ ? If there is, it implies that $b\leq 2a_2-a_1\leq 2m-1$. This is impossible if $C\gt 2m-1$.
Can there be in $A'$ a three-term AP of the form $\lbrace a_1 \lt b \lt c\rbrace$ with $a_1\in A$ ? If there is, it implies that $a_1=2c-b=x_{k+1}$ which is impossible by the choice of $x_{k+1}$.
So $A'$ is Salem-Spencer. Take now $j\geq 3$.
If $j\not\in\lbrace b,c,\frac{b+1}{2},\frac{c+1}{2}\rbrace$, then $I_{j}\cap \lbrace b,c \rbrace=\emptyset$, so $I_{j}\cap A'=I_{j}\cap A \neq I_j$ since $A$ is nice. It then follows that
$I_j\not\subseteq A'$.
If $j\in\lbrace b,c,\frac{b+1}{2},\frac{c+1}{2}\rbrace$, then $|I_{j}\cap \lbrace b,c \rbrace|\leq 1$. Furthermore, if $I_{j}\cap A$ is not empty and contains an $a\in A$, it implies that $\frac{b+1}{2} \leq j \leq a \leq m$ and hence $b\leq 2m-1$, which is impossible if $C\gt 2m-1$.
So we see that $A'$ is nice.
Finally, since $A$ already satisfies $P_k$ and $\lbrace x_{k+1},y_{k+1},z_{k+1}\rbrace$ is a three-term AP (with $y_{k+1}=b,z_{k+1}=c$), we see that $A'$ satisfies $P_{k+1}$. This finishes the proof of the fundamental lemma.
We can then iterate this lemma : starting from $A_3=\lbrace 2,3,8\rbrace$ which satisfies $P_3$, we
construct an increasing sequence $A_3\subset A_4 \subseteq A_5 \subseteq \ldots$ such that each $A_k$ and satisfies $P_k$ (and incidentally $|A_k|=2k-3$).
Let $A_{\infty}=\bigcup_{j\geq 3} A_j$. Then, by construction, $A_{\infty}$ is nice and for every $k\geq 3$, we have $x_k\in I_k$, $y_k,z_k\in A_{\infty}$ such that $\lbrace x_k,y_k,z_k\rbrace$ is a three-term AP.
Let $M$ be any maximal Salem-Spencer set containing $A_{\infty}$. For every $k\geq 3$, since $M$ contains $y_k$ and $z_k$ it cannot contain $x_k$, so $I_k\not\subseteq M$. In other words, $M$ is nice. It is then clear that $M$ satisfies all your conditions.

Could the downvoter please explain his or her reasons ?
